How do you judge the economic state of a region?
I would like to know what parameters people typically use to judge how a region(could be a country, state, or any sub-divisions) is functioning on economic terms. I feel that different places warrant different kinds of variables apart from the the big ones (pci, gdp g.r, etc.). So, i guess it would be insightful to know about the different logics that people go about in economically estimating a region.
Thanks:)

please, take a look at this  World Bank list at first, and choose which indicators you like.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
